# Parent instance <Company at 0x7f0475536f10> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'addresses'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Firstly, I have seen question related to this multiple times. However, I did not understand the solution and some of them did not work for me. I used `lazy='subquery'` and that did not work as well.

This is the table

```
class Company(Base):
    id: uuid.UUID = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4())
    owner_id: uuid.UUID = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    name: str = Column(String(200), nullable=False, index=True)
    is_active: bool = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    addresses: List[Address] = relationship('Address', back_populates='company')
    posts: List[Post] = relationship('Post', back_populates='company')

class Address(Base):
    id: uuid.UUID = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4())
    address_1: str = Column(String(100))
    address_2: str = Column(String(100))
    country: str = Column(String(100))
    city: str = Column(String(100))
    zipcode: str = Column(String(20))
    # profile_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('profile.id'))
    company_id: uuid.UUID = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('company.id'))
    company = relationship('Company', back_populates='addresses')


In my case, I need to insert in 3 tables while creating a company. 

async def company_create(info: Info, input: CompanyCreateInput) -> CompanyCreateResult:
    try:
        address = input.address
        input_without_address = dict(filter(lambda x: x[0] != 'address', input.__dict__.items())) # needs improvement
        data = CompanyCreate(owner_id=user.id, **input_without_address, address=address.__dict__)
    except ValidationError as err:
        error_msg = [Error(loc=str(e['loc']), msg = str(e['msg'])) for e in json.loads(err.json())]
        return CompanyCreateError(error=error_msg)
    async with async_session() as session:
        if await company_by_name(session=session, name=data.name) is not None:
            return CompanyCreateError(error=[Error(loc="name", msg="Name already exists.")])
            company, address = await create_company(input, owner_id=user.id, address=input.address, session=session)
            print("dir company", company.addresses)
        print('company, address', company.id)
            # company.address = address
    return CompanyCreateSuccess(company=cast(CompanyType, company))


async def create_company(company_input: CompanyCreate, owner_id, address, session: AsyncSession) -> Optional[Company]:
    print("company_input", company_input, owner_id, address)
    input_without_address = dict(filter(lambda x: x[0] != 'address', company_input.__dict__.items()))
    company = Company(**input_without_address, owner_id=owner_id)
    session.add(instance=company)
    await session.flush()
    company_user = CompanyUser(user_id=owner_id, company_id=company.id)
    session.add(instance=company_user)
    await session.flush()
    address = Address(**address.__dict__, company_id=company.id)
    session.add(instance=address)
    await session.commit()
    return (company, address)
```

I cannot able to access `addresses` because of which None is returned while casting `company` object with `CompanyType`. Can anyone explain me what this problem is saying based on my code scenario?

Note: I am using **sqlalchemy 1.4**